# Get search results from other websites into my website

Tags: java, php

Recently I came accross a website, if you wish you can check this [link](http://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/).

In this site, user can search for a product and result is collected from different other sites and shown in an order. However when a user clicks a particular link of a product then user is redirected to that site where the search result came from.

Now my question is how this is implemented in terms of Java? Is it by calling webservices published by those sites or just by passing the query to that site's search engine?

I am thinking about `HTTPRequest`. Pleae help me Or should I find something in PHP?

Comment: java or PHP is just a programming language. which language do your web server support? is your web server a Tomcat / Apache / others ?

Comment: server is tomcat. how can i start. I am not able to find anything on google

Comment: You can't find HTTP Request / Call Web Services with Java in Google ?

Comment: i want to know that Can I search a query in stackoverflow search box from my own application search box?

Comment: as long as you know the input parameters, you can.

Comment: How to get the result from there?

Comment: Developer Console > Network can capture some of the information you need. You'd better ask the site you want to query for its parameters (hope you are not doing it without the site's permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jsoup](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/). It is a java library which will let you connect to URL and parse through the resulting HTML.

You can probably use the URL like http://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/search?q=nokia and iterate through the divs in the resulting html to figure out which results you want to look at.

Comment: BTW, you need to know what you are doing. Typically web admins are not happy about bots scrapping their site to steal information, and you won't get past a captcha with this approach.